# Get index of an item from list maintained by QStringListModel()

Tags: python-2.7, pyside

As `QStringListModel()` has only two functions:`setStringList()` & `stringList()`

How to get index of an item from list maintained using `QStringListModel()`?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit vague, so I've tried to cover multiple cases.  Here are some examples, trying to find the index of a list item with value 'stuff'.

```
# Assume that the QStringListModel is called strModel

# Get the QModelIndex of the first matching item
qModelIndex = strModel.match(strModel.index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, 'stuff')[0]

# Get a list of all matching QModelIndex'es (if your list has multiples)
qModelIndeces = strModel.match(strModel.index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, 'stuff', hits=-1)

# If you are trying to get just an int
# Special note: This line works in PySide because stringList() returns a Python list.
#  But it will not work in PyQt4 because stringList() returns a QStringList object.
index = strModel.stringList().index('stuff')  # raises a ValueError if item not found

# Getting just an int, if your list has multiples
indexList = [i for i, item in enumerate(strList) if item=='stuff']
```

Comment: Very nice approaches. Shouldn't it be `stringList().indexOf()` ([documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html#indexOf))?

Comment: Yes, the `indexOf()` function should make that line work in PyQt4.  (I haven't tested it out, but it looks correct.)  The original question was flagged with PySide, so I geared it towards that.  Thanks for adding the PyQt4 version.